# iOS - Connection checker with Reachability class is failed. (reachabilityWithHostName:)

Tags: ios, reachability, internet-connection

I wrote a connection checker using Apple's Reachability class' reachabilityWithHostName: method. Here is my code.

```
-(BOOL)checkConnection{
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.example.com"];
NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if (remoteHostStatus != NotReachable) {
    return YES;
}
else {return NO;}
}
```

SO here is the use cases:

- if I have wifi connection**       : returns YES as expected.
- If I have cellular connection    : returns YES as expected.
- If cellular and Wifi is disabled : returns NO as expected.
- If I have WiFi connection; but the DSL cable is unplugged (so the host shouldn't
  be reachable, internet connection is not available.) : **returns YES and it's unexpected.**
- Also if cellular is enabled but at my current position I have no signal : **returns YES and it's unexpected.**

How can I solve these unexpected results?
Thank you.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363713/reachability-lying-about-disconnected-wifi-network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Martin Koles' help I added a html file into the server. It only has a random value inside. Now I check reachability. If server is reachable, I am trying to get the value from html file. Than, if I could get the value returning YES. If I couldn't (the serverValue should be nil) returning NO..

```
-(BOOL)checkConnection{
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.izmirmobil.com"];
NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if (remoteHostStatus != NotReachable) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/getAValue.html"];
    NSError *errr = nil;
    NSStringEncoding enc;
    NSString *serverValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&enc error:&errr];
    if(serverValue)return YES;
    else return NO;

}
else {return NO;}
}
```